# Llave primaria compuesta: error Illegal offset type en laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Soy nuevo en laravel y no sé como solucionar este problema que es el siguiente:

tengo una tabla asi en MySql:

```
Table: propiedad_x_tipo
Columns:
**id_tipo_propiedad** int(11) **PK** 
**id_propiedad** int(11) **PK**
```

Como pueden ver las dos columnas son llaves primarias.

Ahora mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
class Tipo_X_Propiedad extends Model
{
    protected $table='propiedad_x_tipo';
    protected $primaryKey= ['id_tipo_propiedad','id_propiedad'];
    public $timestamps=false;
    protected $fillable=[
        'id_tipo_propiedad',
        'id_propiedad'
    ];
    protected $guarded=[

    ];
}
```

y a la hora de insertar en la base de datos lo realizo así:

```
$tipos_seleccionados=$request->get('tipo_propiedad');

        foreach ($tipos_seleccionados as $key => $value ) {
            $tipo_x_propiedad=new Tipo_X_Propiedad;
            $tipo_x_propiedad->id_tipo_propiedad=$key.$value;
            $tipo_x_propiedad->id_propiedad=(int)$count;
            $tipo_x_propiedad->save();

        }
```

Pero me da un error a la hora de correrlo:

> (1/1) ErrorException
>       Illegal offset type
>       in HasAttributes.php (line 820)
>       at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Illegal offset type', 'C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\XXXX\XXXX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php', 820, array())
>       in HasAttributes.php (line 820)

Comment: Buenas Compañeros, la solucion que tuve que hacer fue quitar las dos llaves primarias y ya funciono el codigo. Si tienen otra solucion por favor publicarla para saber que soluciones se tiene o se puede hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente Eloquent **NO** soporta llaves primarias compuestas. Puedes ver más información (en inglés) en el siguiente enlace: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

También, en el archivo que extienden los modelos `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php` se puede ver que Eloquent / Laravel espera un string en el valor de $primaryKey y probablemente sea esa la causa de tu error, a continuación el código que te menciono:

```
abstract class Model implements ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Jsonable, JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable
{

    // ...

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    // ...
```